# Cannot fetch all jobs from gitlab with curl

Tags: curl, gitlab

Due to this bug

> https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/216900

I need to fetch the job Id from the job name.

I execute something like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: asdasdasd" https://gitlab.xyz.net/api/v4/projects/982/jobs?scope=success
```

What I get is an incomplete list of jobs and this does not seem to be documented by `gitlab`.
If a job is too old so too down in the list, it's not fetched.
I have to re-execute it to put it on top and make it available.

Is there a way to fetch all jobs or filter better?

Many jobs for example have status "failed" despite the filter "scope=success".

Comment: Did you check if there is no pagination for this large result ? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#keyset-based-pagination

Comment: @NicolasPepinster Good point, thanks. If I execute it with `--head` and add a `per_page` attribute, I see that my values are totally ignored. Always `x-per-page: 20` 
 (default). It cannot fetch more than 100 items that is the maximum `x-per-page` possible value. Looks like a bug to me